# Centos 7 installer shows incorrect free space

Tags: installation, centos7

I booted from a USB to install centos7 onto another USB.

However, when I tried to select the installation destination, the installer showed incorrect (very little) free space on all my devices, shown as in the figure below.

Indeed both sdb and sdc are empty, formatted in FAT32 and NTFS, respectively. 
sda is the HDD on my PC, which is also only about 50% full.

Anyone knows how this can happen?

[installation destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDtSB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

OK, the answer seems that I have to delete the partition first on the "installation destination" page, although the devices are originally empty. After deletion the devices become completely free and I can allocate the mount points.